# Find all positive integers $n$ such that $\,2^{n-1}\cdot n+1\,$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

So I'm searching a certain $n\in \mathbb Z\,$ that satisfies $2^{n-1}\cdot n+1=y^2$.

How do I find the different solutions and how do I prove this?

I think that it would be possible to transform the equation to a sort of Pell equation: $$y^2-n \cdot 2^{n-1}= 1$$

Only this is not a Pell's equation because $n-1$ would have to be $2$.

Does another form exist?

Comment: $n=5$ is a solution... maybe this can help

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Rewrite this equation as $2^{n-1} \cdot n =y^2-1=(y-1)(y+1)$. Then note that if $n>1$, the RHS is even, so $y$ is odd, and hence $y+1$ and $y-1$ are even. However, only one of them can be divisible by four, so either $y+1$ or $y-1$ is divisible by $2^{n-2}$. Now deduce that the RHS will get too large for larger $n$.

Comment: Or, in other words, one of $y-1$ and $y+1$ is at least $2^{n-2}$ and the other is at most $2n$. So as soon as $2n + 2 < 2^{n-2}$ the equation becomes impossible, and this inequality already holds for $n=6$.